# Elasticsearch change field type from filter dissect

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-logback-encoder

I use `logstash-logback-encoder` to send java log files to logstash, and then to elasticsearch. To parse the `message` in java log, I use following filter to dissect message

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/MacBook-201965/Work/java/logs/oauth-logstash.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  if "EXECUTION_TIME" in [tags] {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{endpoint} timeMillis:[%{execution_time_millis}] data:%{additional_data}"
      }
    }
    mutate {
      convert => { "execution_time_millis" => "integer" }
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
     hosts => "localhost:9200"
     index => "elk-%{+YYYY}"
     document_type => "log"
  }

  stdout {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

It dissect the message so I can get value of `execution_time_millis`. However the data type is string. I created the index using Kibana index pattern. How can I change the data type of `execution_time_millis` into long?

Here is the sample json message from logback

```
{  
   "message":"/tests/{id} timeMillis:[142] data:2282||0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
   "logger_name":"com.timpamungkas.oauth.client.controller.ElkController",
   "level_value":20000,
   "endpoint":"/tests/{id}",
   "execution_time_millis":"142",
   "@version":1,
   "host":"macbook201965s-MacBook-Air.local",
   "thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-7",
   "path":"/Users/MacBook-201965/Work/java/logs/oauth-logstash.log",
   "@timestamp":"2018-01-04T11:20:20.100Z",
   "level":"INFO",
   "tags":[  
      "EXECUTION_TIME"
   ],
   "additional_data":"2282||0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
}{  
   "message":"/tests/{id} timeMillis:[110] data:2280||0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
   "logger_name":"com.timpamungkas.oauth.client.controller.ElkController",
   "level_value":20000,
   "endpoint":"/tests/{id}",
   "execution_time_millis":"110",
   "@version":1,
   "host":"macbook201965s-MacBook-Air.local",
   "thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-5",
   "path":"/Users/MacBook-201965/Work/java/logs/oauth-logstash.log",
   "@timestamp":"2018-01-04T11:20:19.780Z",
   "level":"INFO",
   "tags":[  
      "EXECUTION_TIME"
   ],
   "additional_data":"2280||0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already indexed the documents, you'll have to reindex the data after changing the datatype of any field.

However, you can use something like this to change the type of `millis` from string to integer. (`long` is not supported in this)

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert

Also, try defining elasticsearch template before creating index if are going to add multiple index with index names having some regex pattern.Else, you can define your index format beforehand too an then start indexing.

Comment: Check your indexed data after this, `execution_time-millis' will be indexed as integer.

Comment: Thanks, I've done as you suggested too before. It happens that I have typo on filter mutate. It works now.